# how to convert a list data into json format

Tags: c#, json, linq

Hi all i want to convert a list which contain 36 rows of value i want to change this in specific format like this

```
"rows": [{
    "id": 1,
    "cell": ["1", "Super Item", "300", "test", "test1", "test2,", "test3,", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7", "test8", "test9", "test11", "test12", "test13", "test14", "test15", "test16", "test17", "test18", "test19", "test20", "test21", "test22", "test23", "test24", "test25", "test26", "test27", 0, null, false, false]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "cell": ["2", "Item 1", "100", "test", "test1", "test2,", "test3,", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7", "test8", "test9", "test11", "test12", "test13", "test14", "test15", "test16", "test17", "test18", "test19", "test20", "test21", "test22", "test23", "test24", "test25", "test26", "test26", 1, 1, false, false]
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "cell": ["3", "Sub Item 1", "50", "test", "test1", "test2,", "test3,", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7", "test8", "test9", "test11", "test12", "test13", "test14", "test15", "test16", "test17", "test18", "test19", "test20", "test21", "test22", "test23", "test24", "test25", "test26", "test26", 2, 2, true, true]
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "cell": ["4", "Sub Item 2", "25", "test", "test1", "test2,", "test3,", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7", "test8", "test9", "test11", "test12", "test13", "test14", "test15", "test16", "test17", "test18", "test19", "test20", "test21", "test22", "test23", "test24", "test25", "test26", "test26", 2, 2, false, false]
  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "cell": ["5", "Sub-sub Item 1", "25", "test", "test1", "test2,", "test3,", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7", "test8", "test9", "test11", "test12", "test13", "test14", "test15", "test16", "test17", "test18", "test19", "test20", "test21", "test22", "test23", "test24", "test25", "test26", "test26", 3, 4, true, true]
  }, {
    "id": 6,
    "cell": ["6", "Sub Item 3", "25", "test", "test1", "test2,", "test3,", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7", "test8", "test9", "test11", "test12", "test13", "test14", "test15", "test16", "test17", "test18", "test19", "test20", "test21", "test22", "test23", "test24", "test25", "test26", "test26", 2, 2, true, true]
  }, {
    "id": 7,
    "cell": ["7", "Item 2", "200", "test", "test1", "test2,", "test3,", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7", "test8", "test9", "test11", "test12", "test13", "test14", "test15", "test16", "test17", "test18", "test19", "test20", "test21", "test22", "test23", "test24", "test25", "test26", "test26", 0, null, false, false]
  }, {
    "id": 8,
    "cell": ["8", "Sub Item 1", "100", "test", "test1", "test2,", "test3,", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7", "test8", "test9", "test11", "test12", "test13", "test14", "test15", "test16", "test17", "test18", "test19", "test20", "test21", "test22", "test23", "test24", "test25", "test26", "test26", 1, 7, false, false]
  }, {
    "id": 9,
    "cell": ["9", "Sub-sub Item 1", "50", "test", "test1", "test2,", "test3,", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7", "test8", "test9", "test11", "test12", "test13", "test14", "test15", "test16", "test17", "test18", "test19", "test20", "test21", "test22", "test23", "test24", "test25", "test26", "test26", 2, 8, true, true]
  }, {
    "id": 10,
    "cell": ["10", "Sub-sub Item 2", "50", "test", "test1", "test2,", "test3,", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7", "test8", "test9", "test11", "test12", "test13", "test14", "test15", "test16", "test17", "test18", "test19", "test20", "test21", "test22", "test23", "test24", "test25", "test26", "test26", 1, 8, false, true]
  }, {
    "id": 11,
    "cell": ["11", "Sub Item 2", "100", "test", "test1", "test2,", "test3,", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7", "test8", "test9", "test11", "test12", "test13", "test14", "test15", "test16", "test17", "test18", "test19", "test20", "test21", "test22", "test23", "test24", "test25", "test26", "test26", 2, 8, true, true]
  }, {
    "id": 12,
    "cell": ["12", "Super Item", "300", "test", "test1", "test2,", "test3,", "test4", "test5", "test6", "test7", "test8", "test9", "test11", "test12", "test13", "test14", "test15", "test16", "test17", "test18", "test19", "test20", "test21", "test22", "test23", "test24", "test25", "test26", "test26", 0, null, false, false]
  }
]
```

how can i chage this list into like this format of json

```
var res = new List<FlatProduct>();
```

i have a list of flatproduct .

Comment: It would be nice to see your FlatProduct object, we can merly guess what the properties are representing now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON serialization is supported out of the box from .NET 3.5. You have to reference `System.Runtime.Serialization` and `System.ServiceModel.Web`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    [DataContract]
    public class FlatProduct
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string[] cell { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var flatProducts = new List<FlatProduct>
            {
                new FlatProduct { id = "1", cell = new string[2]{"1", "Super Item"} },
                new FlatProduct { id = "2", cell = new string[2]{"2", "Item 1"} }
            };
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(flatProducts.GetType());
            using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(stream, flatProducts);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you can put more items in the `string[]` of `FlatProduct`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Json.NET from codeplex

http://json.codeplex.com/